# Ampersand Operator in Mixed Managed/Unmanaged C++/CLI Project

Tags: .net, c++-cli, smart-pointers, mixed-mode

In writing a function within a C++/CLI ref class, I wish to pass a pointer to a pointer to an object when calling a native function.

**Native Function**

```
void MyNativeFunc(NativeObject** obj);
```

**Managed C++/CLI Function**

```
ref class ManagedType
{
    static NativeObject* m_NativeObj;
    void MyManagedFunc()
    {
        MyNativeFunc(&m_NativeObj);  // Error here
    }
}
```

The problem here is that `&m_NativeObj` in C++/CLI is not a `NativeObject**`. It is an `interior_ptr<NativeObject*>` which the native function cannot accept. Is there an syntax such that I can perform this simple reference operation without incurring the managed pointer?

**Edit:**
Apologies. Initially, the `m_NativeObj` was a function member in the question, not a static member of the class. I have the problem only if it is a static member.

Comment: maybe (NativeObject**)(&m_NativeObj)?

Comment: Tried that. C2440: 'type cast': cannot convert from 'cli::interior_ptr<NativeObj*>' to 'NativeObj**'

Comment: I understand this is the result of the 'NativeObject**' pointer having to be stored on the stack which requires a managed pointer because the reference could change. I'm just looking for the syntax to actually do this. There must be a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the reason your native function is taking a `NativeObject**` is because the function will assign a new object to it, in which case you can do something like this:

```
class NativeObject { };

void MyNativeFunc(NativeObject** obj) {
    *obj = new NativeObject;
}

ref class ManagedObject
{
public:
    void Test()
    {
        NativeObject* p = nullptr;
        MyNativeFunc(&p);
        delete m_NativeObj;
        m_NativeObj = p;
    }

    static NativeObject* m_NativeObj = nullptr;
};
```

On the other hand, if the native function is an in/out function that *may* assign a new value to the pointer, you can code something like this:

```
class NativeObject { };

void MyNativeFunc(NativeObject** obj) {
    if (!(*obj))
        *obj = new NativeObject;
}

ref class ManagedObject
{
public:
    void Test()
    {
        pin_ptr<NativeObject> pinned = m_NativeObj;
        NativeObject* p = pinned;
        MyNativeFunc(&p);
        if (p != m_NativeObj)
        {
            delete m_NativeObj;
            m_NativeObj = p;
        }
    }

    static NativeObject* m_NativeObj = nullptr;
};
```

Comment: I settled on `pin_ptr<NativeObject*> pin = &m_NativeObj;` and passing the `pin` object in place of `&m_NativeObj` as the arguement.